# SSH Agent Forwarding Not Working

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

SSH Agent Forwarding stopped working for me.

Any ideas as to what might be going on? I'm attaching my logs below:

Connecting to the server: http://goo.gl/4xxz9

Connecting to github on server: http://goo.gl/61Wpa

Thanks!

--

Additional Info:

I've been using the ssh forwarding guide on github to troubleshoot - https://help.github.com/articles/using-ssh-agent-forwarding

echo "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" works both on the server and my local machine, and I have checked both .ssh/config and /etc/ssh_config - they're set up correctly.

However, the forwarding doesn't seem to be actually working - "ssh -T git@github.com" works locally, but not if I run it on the server.

Everything's working fine for a colleague - when he runs the "ssh -T git@github.com" command on the server, he authenticates with github successfully.

Comment: It would be helpful to include debug logs from client and server sides of the connection.  You can generate client logs by adding -vvv to your command.

Comment: @DonSimon, I've just added log/debug traces.

Comment: Does public key work locally?  From the first log, it looks like your identification file doesn't exist, and it's trying all possible default key names, but finding none of them.   "Trying private key: /home/launchdevs/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/launchdevs/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/launchdevs/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/launchdevs/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/launchdevs/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/launchdevs/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method"

Comment: Yes - I'm able to pull/push code from my local computer, connect to the server via ssh, etc. I'm assuming this is what you meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recreated my ssh keys, this time with a passphrase, and everything works great.